# How to use the SSD for caching in Windows without Intel Smart Response?

Tags: windows, windows-8, ssd

My motherboard is Asus P8B75-M. It doesn't have Intel Smart Response. But recently I bought a SSD. Since I mostly use linux I have Linux installed in it. But can I use it to speed up Windows also? How? I don't have Smart Response... (I run Windows 8.1). The SSD is only 64GB.

Comment: It would help to have the exact SSD model. Did you receive with it any bundled software such as [Dataplex](http://www.nvelo.com/support/dataplex)?

Comment: An alternative would be to partition off part of the SSD and have it mount on boot as a seperate drive in windows. Now move all of your various temp directories and the like to this drive, also make sure to set any applications working directories to this drive. This should give you a performance increase in windows.

Answer (score 4):

It would help to have the exact SSD model.
Did you receive with it any bundled software such as [Dataplex](http://www.nvelo.com/support/dataplex)?

If not, one alternative to Intel Smart Response Technology is [FancyCache](http://www.romexsoftware.com/en-us/fancy-cache/),
now in 180-day beta testing period.
The drawbacks are firstly its SSD cache is non-persistent cache and gets reset in a reboot.
Secondly, if using write caching with deferred writes you run the risk of data corruption if the system crashes.
Thirdly, using the SSD as a cache will tend to wear out the SSD quicker.
Fourthly, beta software is always risky.

The most I think you can do with an SSD which is too small to install Windows,
is to store on it your documents. You can also install your most-used applications
(installing them in the Program Files folder is just a convention).

Comment: The model is Transcend SSD340

Comment: Dataplex is not supported on Transcend.

Comment: Those are the only alternatives that I am aware of as well.

Answer (score 2):

If your SSD is large enough, you could partition the SSD as two logical drives, and put Linux on one, and install Windows onto the other. There are guides on the internet that describe the partitioning and install process for Windows. Just Google them.

Comment: Actually its only 64GB. Can't install Windows.

Comment: It can still be partitioned as two, unequally sized, logical drives. Then you could use the smaller of the two drives for either your virtual memory or possibly as a cache drive in Windows. In either case you'd just have to Google "setting up SSD as cache in Windows" or "setting up SSD as virtual memory in windows"

Comment: Setting as cache with Smart Response is not available. So I have limited options. One is use Rapid Start and Two is use as virtual memory. What will be the best?