# How to use SSD as a cache to main HDD?

Tags: windows-10, ssd, cache

I installed Windows 10 and a bunch of games on a 500 GB drive. I also have a spare 64 GB SSD lying around. Can I use the SSD as an automatic cache? If so, how? I have looked around a fair bit, but most answers seem to be for Windows 7 or 8, or otherwise outdated. What's the best way to have an SSD cache on a modern Windows 10 computer?

I do not have Intel, so SRT is not an option. This question is not a duplicate of [this other question](https://superuser.com/questions/739918/how-to-use-the-ssd-for-caching-in-windows-without-intel-smart-response) because Dataplex is not supported on my SSD because it is a standard SSD, not a specialized "cache drive", and FancyCache is only supported through Windows 8, and not on Windows 10.

Comment: You will get the best result if you install Win10 on the SSD - which is possible. There is plenty of space. If you do a new install, the SSD will be aligned automatically. If you clone the existing OS, I suggest you first align the SSD. ++> http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/113967-ssd-alignment.html?ltr=S

Comment: @CarlB That question is regarding Windows 8, and is over 2 years old. As I said, I have found many similar questions, and they all seem outdated. I'm posting this question with the hope that things have improved by now.

Comment: @whs I don't really need all of Windows to be on SSD. There are a lot of features I don't use. I'd rather use that space for improved load times on stuff I _do_ use.

Comment: @SchighSchagh - I think if you listed what you tried...like: Did X,Y, and Z from "this question"...What next..I would change my close vote and vote up your question. :)

Comment: @CarlB I tried looking for software or settings to do what the question title says. The only stuff I've found is old (Windows 8 or earlier), or needs specific hardware which I don't have, as opposed to a generic SSD. I'm not sure what more than that I can tell you. I guess the answer here might be that "things haven't improved over the last few years, and you can't do it without specialized hardware."